# Legal implications of Bower License

Tags: bower, bower-install

From the official example from http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#bowerjson

Inside bower.json file they have:

```
"authors": [
    "Betty Beta <bbeta@example.com>"
],
"license": "MIT",
```

Why is this necessary, and will there be any legal implications if we change our release later on, and forget to change this later?

Comment: "_change our release later on, and forget to change this later_" Why does "changing your release" imply a need to change the license?

Comment: This question is off-topic, as it asks for legal interpretation and is not about programming as defined in the [help]. If you want legal advice, consult an attorney licensed to practice in your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't change the license, then you're all set.  You can change the code and distribute it, and even sell it.

It's not a long licence,  just read it, it will take you 30 seconds.
[MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit)